# docker - cannot find aws credentials in container although they exist

Tags: linux, bash, amazon-web-services, docker

Running the following docker command on `mac` works and on `linux`, running `ubuntu` cannot find the `aws cli` credentials. It returns the following message: `Unable to locate credentials
Completed 1 part(s) with ... file(s) remaining`

The command which runs an image and mounts a data volume and then copies a file from and s3 bucket, and starts the bash shell in the docker container.

`sudo docker run -it --rm -v ~/.aws:/root/.aws username/docker-image sh -c 'aws s3 cp s3://bucketname/filename.tar.gz /home/emailer && cd /home/emailer && tar zxvf filename.tar.gz && /bin/bash'`

What am I missing here?

This is my `Dockerfile`:

```
FROM ubuntu:latest

#install node and npm
RUN apt-get update && \
    apt-get -y install curl && \
    curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup | sudo bash - && \
    apt-get -y install python build-essential nodejs

#install and set-up aws-cli
RUN sudo apt-get -y install \
    git \
    nano \
    unzip && \
    curl "https://s3.amazonaws.com/aws-cli/awscli-bundle.zip" -o "awscli-bundle.zip" && \
    unzip awscli-bundle.zip

RUN sudo ./awscli-bundle/install -i /usr/local/aws -b /usr/local/bin/aws

# Provides cached layer for node_modules
ADD package.json /tmp/package.json
RUN cd /tmp && npm install
RUN mkdir -p /home/emailer && cp -a /tmp/node_modules /home/emailer/
```

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Mounting `$HOME/.aws/` into the container should work. Make sure to mount it as read-only.

It is also worth mentioning, if you have **several profiles** in your `~/.aws/config` -- you must also provide the `AWS_PROFILE=somethingsomething` environment variable. E.g. via `docker run -e AWS_PROFILE=xxx ...` otherwise you'll get the same error message (unable to locate credentials).

**Update:** Added example of the mount command

```sh
docker run -v ~/.aws:/root/.aws …
```

Comment: Could you provide a an example of the mount command we should use with docker run?

Comment: @Cleanshooter sure, here you go

Comment: For Mac users this might not be enough since that folder is not accessible by default by Docker. Newer Docker versions have a simple workaround via the UI though, as shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65602048/8162025).

Answer (score 8):

You can use environment variable instead of copying ~/.aws/credentials and config file into container for aws-cli

`docker run \
        -e AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID=AXXXXXXXXXXXXE \
        -e AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY=wXXXXXXXXXXXXY \
        -e AWS_DEFAULT_REGION=us-west-2 \
        <img>`

Ref: [AWS CLI Doc](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/cli-configure-envvars.html)

Comment: How would you do this via an env-file (without putting the credentials in the env file - but rather just the names of the ENV variables so that they are correctly detected)?

Comment: can i do it with docker build? it's saying "unknown shorthand flag: 'e' in -e"

Answer (score 8):

the only solution that worked for me in this case is:

```
volumes:
  - ${USERPROFILE}/.aws:/root/.aws:ro
```

Comment: This worked for me (though I used `~/.aws` instead of the `$USERPROFILE` var).

Comment: How do you do this using a dockerfile instead of docker compose?

Comment: @ash you can't use it in a dockerfile, cause a dockerfile doesn't have volumes. You can run a docker file using docker run and specify the volumes as commands though. Or you can use a COPY command in the dockerfile to bake your aws credentials file into it, but I wouldn't recommend doing that.

Answer (score 7):

what do you see if you run

```
ls -l ~/.aws/config
```

within your docker instance?

Comment: `-rw------- 1 1000 staff 29 May 25 14:04 /root/.aws/config`

Comment: if do `cat ~/.aws/config` does it show you your access id and secret?

Comment: to be honest I wasn't expecting that.  That error says the problem, It cant find the config file which is usually located at ~/.aws/config.  I suspected the problem was that you were assuming the home directory was /root/ which might not be the case in every instance

Comment: additionally if this is your issue perhaps you should set the environment variable `AWS_CONFIG_FILE=/root/.aws/config` just to double make sure your docker knows exactly where to look

Comment: Ok, one important thing is missing here is the env variable: `AWS_SDK_LOAD_CONFIG=1`

Answer (score 2):

There are a few things that could be wrong.  One, as mentioned previously you should check if your ~/.aws/config file is set accordingly.  If not, you can follow [this link](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/cli-chap-configure.html#cli-quick-configuration) to set it up. Once you have done that you can map the `~/.aws` folder using the `-v` flag on `docker run`.

If your `~/.aws` folder is mapped correctly, make sure to check the permissions on the files under ~/.aws so that they are able to be accessed safely by whatever process is trying to access them.  If you are running as the user process, simply running `chmod 444 ~/.aws/*` should do the trick.  This will give full read permissions to the file.  Of course, if you want write permissions you can add whatever other modifiers you need. Just make sure the read octal is flipped for your corresponding user and/or group.

Comment: yes, for me it was the permission as  @juicedatom  mentionned    chmod 444 ~/.aws/* is the trick

Comment: Doesn't this make the credentials available to all users on the system? Sounds dangerous...

Answer (score 1):

The issue I had was that I was running Docker as root. When running as root it was unable to locate my credentials at `~/.aws/credentials`, even though they were valid.

Directions for running Docker without root on Ubuntu are here: https://askubuntu.com/a/477554/85384

Comment: I had the same issue `~/.aws/credentials` was not loading. I had to use `/root/.aws/credentials`. thank you.

Comment: Should above be mentioned in the docker-compose at Volume right? I tried but still not able to connect to aws

Answer (score 1):

Another case of `Unable to locate credentials` inside docker running on an ec2 with the right IAM profile was due to using metadata HTTP tokens required.

When checking iam security-credentials metadata endpoint it would return 401:

```
curl -I http://169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data/iam/security-credentials/
python
import requests
requests.get('http://169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data/iam/security-credentials/')
```

You're meant to pass a token, see https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/instance-metadata-v2-how-it-works.html

Otherwise set the http token as optional in the instance metadata options config

Answer (score 0):

You just have to pass the credential in order to be the AWS_PROFILE, if you do not pass anything it will use the default, but if you want you can copy the default and add your desired credentials.

In Your credentials

```
[profile_dev]
aws_access_key_id = xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
aws_secret_access_key = xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
output = json
region = eu-west-1
```

In Your docker-compose

```
version: "3.8"
services:
  cenas:
    container_name: cenas_app
    build: .
    ports:
      - "8080:8080"
    environment:
      - AWS_PROFILE=profile_dev
    volumes:
      - ~/.aws:/app/home/.aws:ro
```