# Mounts denied: The paths /var and /var/x are not shared from OS X and are not known to Docker

Tags: macos, docker, jenkins, docker-for-mac

Im trying to run a pipeline job on jenkins based on a jenkins and docker file. As described in the following documentation: https://jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/docker/

Dockerfile (for a vuejs based project):

```
FROM node:8

RUN apt-get update -y

# Puppeteer/Chrome headless deps
RUN apt-get install -yq \
    gconf-service libasound2 libatk1.0-0 libc6 libcairo2 libcups2 libdbus-1-3 \
    libexpat1 libfontconfig1 libgcc1 libgconf-2-4 libgdk-pixbuf2.0-0 \
    libglib2.0-0 libgtk-3-0 libnspr4 libpango-1.0-0 libpangocairo-1.0-0 \
    libstdc++6 libx11-6 libx11-xcb1 libxcb1 libxcomposite1 libxcursor1 \
    libxdamage1 libxext6 libxfixes3 libxi6 libxrandr2 libxrender1 libxss1 \
    libxtst6 ca-certificates fonts-liberation libappindicator1 libnss3 \
    lsb-release xdg-utils wget

# Cypress deps
RUN apt-get install -y \
    libnotify-dev \
    xvfb
```

Jenkinsfile:

```
pipeline {
    agent { dockerfile true }
    stages {
        stage('Test') {
            steps {
                sh 'node --version'
                sh 'npm --version'
            }
        }
    }
}
```

When running the job everything seems to go fine till the following error shows up:

```
java.io.IOException: Failed to run image 'da68b2108e7bcfc2b9c0a6aff8b164ceb8d0da13'. Error: docker: Error response from daemon: Mounts denied: 
The paths /var/root/.jenkins/workspace/test-job@tmp and /var/root/.jenkins/workspace/test-job
are not shared from OS X and are not known to Docker.
You can configure shared paths from Docker -> Preferences... -> File Sharing.
See https://docs.docker.com/docker-for-mac/osxfs/#namespaces for more info.
.
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.docker.workflow.client.DockerClient.run(DockerClient.java:133)
    at 
...
```

Question: [Docker: Mounts denied. The paths ... are not shared from OS X and are not known to Docker](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45122459/docker-mounts-denied-the-paths-are-not-shared-from-os-x-and-are-not-known)
does not lead me to a solution.

**Update**
When I am trying to force docker to use a different folder, e.g. by giving run args to the docker run command:

```
agent { 
  docker {
    image 'da68b2108e7bcfc2b9c0a6aff8b164ceb8d0da13'
      args '-v /Users/../../dev'
    }
}
```

These seem to be ingored:

```
[Pipeline] withDockerContainer
Jenkins does not seem to be running inside a container
$ docker run -t -d -u 0:0 -v /Users/../../dev -w /var/root/.jenkins/workspace/test-job -v /var/root/.jenkins/workspace/test-job:/var/root/.jenkins/workspace/test-job:rw,z -v /var/root/.jenkins/workspace/test-job@tmp:/var/root/.jenkins/workspace/test-job@tmp:rw,z -e
```

Comment: Why would you expect /var/root to be accessible? You say the answer to the linked question isn't helpful but you don't say why, what have you tried.

Comment: Because in the question the person who asks the quest is running the command: docker run -v /var/folders/zz/, which can be changed to private/var. However im not running any similar command, manually.