# Cannot start service mount denied '/usr/local/share/dotnet/sdk/NuGetFallbackFolder\r\n' is not share from macos X and is not know to docker

Tags: c#, macos, docker, asp.net-core, docker-for-mac

I, have created a project in asp.net core 2.0 project on macOS X with docker support on it.Successfully created project and added docker support.

When I run the project I, am getting an error as

**Cannot start service merorentalwebapi: b'Mounts denied: \r\nThe path /usr/local/share/dotnet/sdk/NuGetFallbackFolder\r\nis not shared from OS X and is not known to Docker.\r\nYou can configure shared paths from Docker -> Preferences... -> File Sharing.\r\nSee https://docs.docker.com/docker-for-mac/osxfs/#namespaces for more info.\r\n.'
/Applications/Visual Studio.app/Contents/Resources/lib/monodevelop/AddIns/docker/MonoDevelop.Docker/MSbuild/Sdks/Microsoft.Docker.Sdk/build/Microsoft.VisualStudio.Docker.Compose.targets(363,5): error : Encountered errors while bringing up the project..**

Here is the list from docker preferences

[image: docker support]

Tried some solution from this link [Docker: Mounts denied. The paths ... are not shared from OS X and are not known to Docker](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45122459/docker-mounts-denied-the-paths-are-not-shared-from-os-x-and-are-not-known)
But didn't help me to solve the issue.

How do I fixed this issue as I, am new to .net on apple mac OS .

Answer (score 16):

Solve it need to add this location in docker preference

[image: docker preference]

Comment: this also fixed my problem ! Thanks

Comment: It works. Also documented here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/mac/docker-quickstart?view=vsmac-2019

Comment: Thanks, helped a lot