# nginx does not seeing static files, when launching with docker compose +gunicorn

Tags: django, docker, nginx, docker-compose, django-staticfiles

The thing is that i have set up dockerfiles, docker-compose is running everything as it should be. Databases is connected and all the staff. But the only problem is, that i cant load staticfiles. Gunicorn informs, that files "Not Found" both admin, and rest_framework static files. Even though it creates 'static' in the root directory, but doesn't collect static there, while dockerfile run.

When im doing "docker-compose up" it says that `0 static files were copied to '/static', 165 unmodified

So far i have checked paths which are configured in STATIC_ROOT and STATIC URL.
Also, modified my docker-compose file:

```
version: '3.11'

services:
  django_gunicorn:
    volumes:
      - static:/static/
    env_file:
      - .env
    build:
      context: .
    ports:
      - "8000:8000"
  nginx:
    build: ./nginx
    volumes:
      - ./backend/service/static:/backend/static
    ports:
      - "80:80"
    depends_on:
      - django_gunicorn
      - db
  db:
    image: postgres
    expose:
      - 5432
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_USER=postgres
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=postgres
      - POSTGRES_DB=postgres
volumes:
  static:
```

Also i have inspected nginx config file one more time:

```
upstream django {
    server django_gunicorn:8000;
}

server {
    listen 80;

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://django;
    }
    location /static/ {
        autoindex on;
        alias /static/;
    }
}
```

i have also tried different approaches to setting up root and url of staticfiles, but left it like this for now:

```
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static')
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
```

Also there were suggestions to run "collectstatic" first, which i have already done, but no effect, so ive deleted static folder for now, because i didnt see 'static' folder in other applications as well.

entrypoint/sh

```
#!/bin/sh

python manage.py migrate --no-input
python manage.py collectstatic --no-input

gunicorn config.wsgi:application --bind 0.0.0.0:8000
```

Here is my Dockerfile:

```
FROM python:3.11

RUN pip install --upgrade pip

COPY ./requirements.txt .
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt \
    python manage.py collectstatic \
    pip install python-dotenv
COPY ./backend /app

WORKDIR /app

COPY ./entrypoint.sh /
ENTRYPOINT ["sh", "/entrypoint.sh"]
```

Comment: `Gunicorn informs` gunicorn should not know about such requests.  Maybe Nginx is not using shown config. Please add sample static file url which cannot be resolved and show your nginx dockerfile (maybe rebuild image, restart container beforehand to verify that actual config is in use).

Comment: i guess, gunicorn is just showing logs. also if i delete static folder - it will create it itself and return '165 static files copied to '/app/static'. I dont have folder /app/, so i guess thats in docker container. And static folder which was created is still empty
So, where do that /app/ folder exists? how to use it

Comment: Does this answer your question? [how to make static files works using django docker nginx and postgresql since its not serving them](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66774079/how-to-make-static-files-works-using-django-docker-nginx-and-postgresql-since-it)

Comment: No, i will update my code here, with that correction. I have already tried that, but nothing help.

Comment: show your django dockerfile

Comment: I have added the dockerfile

Comment: `COPY ./backend /app` this is where `app` folder comes from. Your project is in folder `app` and `static` is under this `BASE_DIR` - that's why you see `/app/static` in `collectstatic` output. Same as the OP in the thread I gave link to had everything under `/backend` folder you have everything under `/app` folder and both his and your configuration do not take this into account. Both issues are similar. Take a look at that thread and make your configuration files  matching folder structure.

Comment: `./backend/service/static:/backend/static` this looses mapping to the virtual volume `static:` and points to non existent `/backend/static` whereas your static files are at `/app/static`

Comment: as i understand /app/ exists in docker container, and not in the project root. backend/static exists in my project, and have no clue where to find app/static/ and use it.

Comment: thank you very much, for your help. i will inspect it again, more carefully.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nginx must map STATIC_URL to STATIC_ROOT with respect to volume mapping in docker-compose.

**docker-compose** volume mapping for **Nginx**:

`- static:/static/`

virtual volume "static" to root directory `/static/`

**Nginx** location

```
location /static/ {
    autoindex on;
    alias /static/;
}
```

Maps STATIC_URL = `/static/` to directory inside nginx container `/static/` which matches docker-compose volume mapping we just mentioned. Location is supposed to match `STATIC_URL` because Django is generating those URLs and it does use STATIC_URL so static files URLs will begin with STATIC_URL and to catch those URLs nginx must use the same location. But alias value is not supposed to match STATIC_ROOT because we "deliver" static files to nginx via virtual volume mapping in docker-compose and they (static files) will appear for nginx just where we tell them to - `- static:/static/` - nginx *container* will see them under `/static/` path. Django settings do not affect this path.

**Django project** docker image

`COPY ./backend /app`

which means that `BASE_DIR` *inside* the container will be `/app` and this is exactly what `collectstatic` is reporting to you: `'165 static files copied to '/app/static'`

now we need to share those files with nginx via virtual volume by mapping virtual volume to the directory inside django project container with collected static files. Static files were collected to `/app/static`. Virtual volume shared with nginx is `static`, so

**docker-compose** volume mapping for **Django project**

`- static:/app/static/`

[image]

Comment: all the love and respect, my friend! Thank you very much, for your effort and help!

Comment: Hi Ivan can you look at my post? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76100977/django-not-getting-static-files-in-docker