# Django project - JS not loading after moving it out of HTML to own file in static folder

Tags: django, django-templates, django-staticfiles

When i had the JS directly in the HTML file, everything worked as expected. Since I moved it to a spots.js file, it doesn't load or appear in the network tab, but i can reach it by going to file location in the server. I am in Debug mode.

In my settings.py I have:

```
STATIC_URL = '/users/static/'
STATICFILES_DIRS = [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static')]
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'var', 'static')
```

In my urls.py, I have:

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('', home, name='users-home'),
    path('register/', RegisterView.as_view(), name='users-register'),
    path('profile/', profile, name='users-profile'),
    path('select-spots/', select_spots, name='select-spots'),
] + static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT)
```

In my views.py I have:

```
@login_required
def select_spots(request):
    spots = []
    with open('spotscsv.csv') as csvfile:
        reader = csv.DictReader(csvfile)
        for row in reader:
            spots.append({
                'name': row['name'],
                'latitude': float(row['latitude']),
                'longitude': float(row['longitude']),
            })
    return render(request, 'users/select_spots.html', {'spots': spots})
```

And in my select_spots.html, I have:

```
{% extends 'users/base.html' %}
{% load static %}

<script src="{% static 'myapp/spots.js' %}"></script>
```

Folder structure:

[image: Here is my folder organization]

I tried changing the spots location, modifying code, running `collectstatic` with no luck.

Comment: Can you please share your console error log?

Comment: What is Django rendering in <script src=“”> on the webpage? Check using inspect element

Answer (score 0):

Some of settings are pointing nowhere or misused.

### STATIC_URL

`STATIC_URL = '/users/static/'`

this looks like attempt to map to the folder `/users/static/myapp/..` but `STATIC_URL` is not about folders, it's the root URL for referencing static files in templates. Try changing it to

`STATIC_URL = '/how_i_reach_my_static_files/'`

feel free to shorten it after you realize how every settings option affects static files setup

### STATIC_ROOT

`STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'var', 'static')`

This option *cannot have wrong value*. It's the folder which is supposed to be *mapped* to `STATIC_URL` and *where to* all the static files will be delivered after running `collectstatic`. `BASE_DIR/var/static/` seems to exist thus this option is configured fine.

### STATICFILES_DIRS

`STATICFILES_DIRS = [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static')]`

this thing is ruined, it is pointing to nowhere. [`STATICFILES_DIRS`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/ref/settings/#staticfiles-dirs) is a list of places *where from* static files should be collected to `STATIC_ROOT` during `collectstatic`. You don't have `BASE_DIR/static` folder. And I guess `collectstatic` command log currently is saying that it did not do a thing.

Instead you have `static` folder under `users` app. Valid path to this folder would be

`STATICFILES_DIRS = [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'users', 'static')]`

However Django has built-in tool for collecting all the `static` folders from any app with no need to list them all in `STATICFILES_DIRS` manually. To achieve this you need to set [`STATICFILES_FINDERS`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/ref/settings/#staticfiles-finders) like this

```
[
    "django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.FileSystemFinder",
    "django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.AppDirectoriesFinder",
]
```

actually this is the default value.

### myapp/spots.js

After you fix thing mentioned above you can run `collectstatic` and it will list found static files and copy them to `STATIC_ROOT` = `BASE_DIR/var/static`. If you look into this folder you will notice that all the static files copied from specific apps are located in folders named after those apps. And `myapp/spots.js` will be stored under

`/var/static/users/myapp/` - because it came from app `users`

Which means that URL

`{% static 'myapp/spots.js' %}`

is wrong. Correct one would be

`{% static 'users/myapp/spots.js' %}`

### have a look at

- [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/howto/static-files/) are pretty straightforward and very verbose.
- django [admin](https://github.com/django/django/tree/main/django/contrib/admin) app which is a *regular* app and is organized *as supposed to*:

  - there is a folder `admin/static`
  - files are [referenced](https://github.com/django/django/blob/main/django/contrib/admin/templates/admin/base.html#L12) like this `{% static "admin/css/responsive.css" %}`
  - if you included `admin` into `INSTALLED_APPS` then after running `collectstatic` you will see folder `var/static/admin`
  - use this setup as an example and do similarly
- [some](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66437690/django-html-template-cant-find-static-css-and-js-files/66439076#66439076) [other](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75365356/nginx-does-not-seeing-static-files-when-launching-with-docker-compose-gunicorn/75384047?noredirect=1#comment134211131_75384047) [answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66833381/static-media-images-are-not-displaying-in-django/66834540#66834540)