# Server static files from different machine with docker containers and nginx as reverse proxy

Tags: django, nginx, reverse-proxy, static-files

I have a two machines. First machine runs several docker containers (django(uwsgi), db and nginx). Second server runs also several docker containers ( django(dahpne), redis, db ).

On first machine nginx serves static files from Django(uwsgi) everything work correctly.

**I'm trying to configure nginx to serve static files also from the second server. Without success. Please help me I'm out of ideas.**

I tried many things and my current configuration looks like:

nginx (on first machine)

```
map $http_upgrade $connection_upgrade {
        default upgrade;
        '' close;
    }

...

server {
    listen      443 ssl;
    server_name ${DOMAIN} www.${DOMAIN};

access_log  /var/log/nginx/access.log main;
error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;

ssl_certificate     /etc/letsencrypt/live/${DOMAIN}/fullchain.pem;
ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/${DOMAIN}/privkey.pem;

include     /etc/nginx/options-ssl-nginx.conf;

ssl_dhparam /vol/proxy/ssl-dhparams.pem;

add_header Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=31536000; includeSubDomains" always;

location /static {
    alias /vol/static;     
}

location / {
    uwsgi_pass              ${P1_HOST}:${P1_PORT};
    include                 /etc/nginx/uwsgi_params;
    client_max_body_size    10M;
}

location /dashboard {
    proxy_pass http://dashboardproject;
    proxy_http_version 1.1;
    proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
    proxy_set_header Connection $connection_upgrade;
    proxy_set_header Host $host;

    #proxy_redirect off;        
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host $server_name;

    location /dashboard/d2/static {
        alias /vol/web/static/dashboard/;
        #try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
    }
}
```

}
Proxy docker compose

```
...
  proxy:
    build:
      context: ./proxy

    ...

    volumes:
      - certbot-web:/vol/www
      - proxy-dhparams:/vol/proxy
      - certbot-certs:/etc/letsencrypt
      - static-data:/vol/static
    networks:
      - p_internal_network

volumes:
  certbot-web:
  proxy-dhparams:
  certbot-certs:
  postgres-data:
  static-data:
...
```

And the configuration of docker compose on second server

```
version: "3.9"

services:
  dashboard:
    build:
      context: ./dashboard
    restart: always
    networks:
      - d2_internal_network
    volumes:
      - static-data:/vol/web/static/dashboard
    environment:
      - DASHBOARD_SECRET_KEY=${DASHBOARD_SECRET_KEY}
      - DASHBOARD_ALLOWED_HOSTS=${DOMAIN},www.${DOMAIN}
      - DASHBOARD_CSRF_TRUSTED_ORIGINS=https://${DOMAIN},https://www.${DOMAIN}
      - DB_HOST=db
      - DB_PORT=${DB_PORT}
      - DB_NAME=${DB_NAME}
      - DB_USER=${DB_USER}
      - DB_PASS=${DB_PASS}
      - REDIS_URL=redis
    ports:
      - "9800:9200"
    depends_on:
      - db
      - redis
      
  ...

networks:
  d2_internal_network:
```

volumes:
postgres-data:
static-data:

And relevant Django settings.py lines:

```
STATIC_URL = '/dashboard/d2/static/'
MEDIA_URL = 'dashboard/d2/static/media/'

MEDIA_ROOT='/vol/web/media'
STATIC_ROOT='/vol/web/static/dashboard/'

PROTECTED_ROOT='/vol/web/protected'

STATICFILES_DIRS = (os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static'),)
```

If something important is missing I'd be glad to add it.

Comment: looks like similar to this one https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76395528/django-does-not-serve-static-files-for-ckeditor-in-docker-container#comment134712515_76395528