# Nginx and Gunicorn Static files not being found in my docker-compose django project even if logs show '125 static files copied to '/app/static''

Tags: django, nginx, docker-compose, static, gunicorn

I have set up my nginx folder, Dockerfile, .env, docker-compose.yml and entrypoint.sh files, and everything is running okay and I'm able to see pages as it should be. But the only problem is I can't load staticfiles. The `gunicorn` container logs are showing

> "Not Found" and the nginx container is showing failed (2: No such file
> or directory).

These are my configuration files:

***docker-compose.yml***

```
version: '3'

services:
  marathon_gunicorn:
    volumes:
      - static:/static
    env_file:
      - .env
    build: 
      context: .
    ports:
      - "8010:8000"
      
  nginx:
    build: ./nginx
    volumes:
      - static:/static
    ports:
      - "8012:80"
    depends_on:
      - marathon_gunicorn

  db:
    image: postgres:15
    container_name: postgres_db
    restart: always
    environment:
      POSTGRES_DB: xxx
      POSTGRES_USER: xxx
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: xxx
    volumes:
      - pg_data:/var/lib/postgresql/data

volumes:
  static:
  pg_data:`
```

***entrypoint.sh***

```
#!/bin/sh

# Apply database migrations
python manage.py migrate --no-input

# Collect static files
python manage.py collectstatic --no-input

# Start Gunicorn server
gunicorn absamarathon.wsgi:application --bind 0.0.0.0:8000
```

***Django Dockerfile***

```
FROM python:3.8

RUN pip install --upgrade pip
COPY ./requirements.txt .
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt

COPY ./absamarathon /app

WORKDIR /app

COPY ./entrypoint.sh /
ENTRYPOINT [ "sh", "/entrypoint.sh" ]
```

***nginx/default.conf***

```
upstream django {
    server marathon_gunicorn:8000;
}

server {
    listen 80;

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://django;
    }

    location /static/ {
    alias /static/;
}

    # location /media/ {
    #     alias /app/media/;
    # }
}
```

***settings.py***

```
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static')
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
```

Answer (score 0):

Your ngix configuration isn't right as it doesn't handle static right, because you didn't tell nginx where is the folder to server /static. You shall put `/static/` above `/` so it matches first.

```
server {
     listen 80;

     location /static/ {
        alias /app/static/;
      }

     location / {
        proxy_pass http://django;
      }
```

}

Comment: Hi @Mohamed, so i only edited my default.conf and included /app before the static. However the result is still the same. Do you think it has anything to do with any other of my configuration settings?

Comment: Is Django responsing, in other words, Are STATIC_FILES your only problem?

Comment: Yes, Django is responding and I'm able to load pages and see the html components but all static files are not loading ie css, js and images

Comment: Ah I get it now, You have a container for nginx separate from Django, right?

Comment: Exactly! yes I do. could that be the reason?

Comment: Yes because `/app/static/` isn't on the same container so either you update your DOCKERFILE to move static/ to nginx container instead of Django container, or remove ngix and use whitenoise instead to serve staticfiles from Django container

Comment: How do I update my Docker file to move static to nginx? because I would still like to use nginx for its load balancing functionalities

Comment: In Docker file add a new FROM nginx, and WORKDIR /app and COPY /static /static.

Comment: Hi Mohamed, so just for clarity im adding this to my django Dockerfile or Nginx Dockerfile?

Comment: According to your question at the start, you have one DOCKERFILE so you can add this to the DOCKER File to create another image from nginx

Answer (score 0):

Create and attach volume to your container,

**docker-compose.yml**

```
volumes:
     static_files:
         name: static_files

nginx:
  build: ./nginx
  volumes:
    - static:/static
  ports:
    - "8012:80"
  depends_on:
    - marathon_gunicorn
  volumes:
    - static_files:/app/static:ro
```

Answer (score 0):

Nginx config looks fine but virtual volume mapping for Django container is broken.

In Django docker image you defined

`COPY ./absamarathon /app`

thus your project `BASE_DIR` is `/app` folder. In Django project settings you defined

`STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static')`

thus static files location is `/app/static`.

But in docker-compose config you map virtual volume `static` to container folder `/static` instead of `/app/static`.

For `marathon_gunicorn` container change volume mapping to

`static:/app/static`

Don't change it for Nginx container. Also you it may be helpful to see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75384047/5921826) on SO.