Why /static/ not showing up for /admin in Django project?
So, I've been trying a bunch of things. Settings look good to me but maybe I am missing something.
I use: PostegreySQL, Reddis, Celery beat, nginx, gunicorn.
I can't figure out what the problem is: maybe it's a permission issue, maybe it's the directories...
I just can't figure out what fails.
enter image description here
[error] 280897#280897: *40433 open() "/app/crm_market/collected_static/grappelli/js/grappelli.min.js" failed (2: No such file or directory), client: 31.128.32.152, server: my_domen.com, request: "GET /static/grappelli/js/grappelli.min.js HTTP/1.1", host: "my_domen.com", referrer: "https://my_domen.com/admin/login/?next=/admin/"
(venv) root@fuvscqxzga://root/CRM-WB# docker compose exec web ls -l /app/crm_market/collected_static/ total 12 drwxr-xr-x 6 www-data www-data 4096 Jun 25 09:15 admin drwxr-xr-x 4 www-data www-data 4096 Jun 25 09:15 debug_toolbar drwxr-xr-x 9 www-data www-data 4096 Jun 25 09:15 grappelli
project structure:
enter image description here
settings.py:
STATIC_URL = "/static/"
STATICFILES_DIRS = [
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "static"),
]
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "collected_static")

/etc/nginx/sites-enabled/default
server {
    server_name my_domen.com;

    location /static/ {
        alias /app/crm_market/collected_static/;
    }
    location /admin/ {
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8000;
    }

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8000;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
    }

    error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;
    access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;

    listen 443 ssl; 

Dockerfile
FROM python:3.9-slim

WORKDIR /app/crm_market

COPY requirements.txt .

RUN pip install --no-cache-dir -r requirements.txt

COPY . .

EXPOSE 8000

CMD ["gunicorn", "--bind", "0.0.0.0:8000", "CRM-WB.wsgi:application"]

docker-compose.yml
services:
  db:
    image: postgres:latest
    environment:
      POSTGRES_DB: mydatabase
      POSTGRES_USER: myuser
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: mypassword
    volumes:
      - db_data:/var/lib/postgresql/data

  redis:
    image: redis:latest
    command: redis-server --requirepass $REDIS_PASSWORD
    ports:
      - '6379:6379'
    volumes:
      - redisdata:/data
    env_file:
      - .env

  web:
    build: .
    command: >
      sh -c "python manage.py migrate --noinput &&
             python manage.py collectstatic --noinput &&
             gunicorn crm_market.wsgi:application --bind 0.0.0.0:8000"
    volumes:
      - .:/app
      - static_volume:/app/crm_market/collected_static
    ports:
      - "8000:8000"
    depends_on:
      - db
      - redis
    working_dir: /app/crm_market

  worker:
    build: .
    command: celery -A crm_market worker -l info
    volumes:
      - .:/app
    depends_on:
      - db
      - redis
    environment:
      - DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE=crm_market.settings
      - PYTHONPATH=/app/crm_market
    working_dir: /app/crm_market

  beat:
    build: .
    command: celery -A crm_market beat -l info
    volumes:
      - .:/app
    depends_on:
      - db
      - redis
    environment:
      - DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE=crm_market.settings
      - PYTHONPATH=/app/crm_market
    working_dir: /app/crm_market

volumes:
  db_data:
  redisdata:
  static_volume:

I want admin/ to see collected_static. I tried diffrent variants of the nginx, Dockerfile, docker-compose:
Thried to setup access with these commands:
docker compose exec web chown -R www-data:www-data /app/crm_market/collected_static
docker compose exec web chmod -R 755 /app/crm_market/collected_static
docker compose exec web ls -ld /app/crm_market/collected_static
docker compose exec web ls -l /app/crm_market/collected_static/admin/css/base.css
docker compose down
docker compose up -d --build
curl -I https://handonpulse.ru/static/admin/css/base.css

result:
enter image description here
I've tried collecting static manually they don't get applied by docker:
docker compose exec web python manage.py collectstatic --noinput

It looks like there isn't a file in your static_volume volume at /grappelli/js/grappelli.min.js. What does compose exec web ls -l /app/crm_market/collected_static/grappelli/js/grappelli.min.js show?

docker compose exec web ls -l
(celerybeat-schedule,
drwxr-xr-x 5 www-data www-data  4096 collected_static, crm_market, manage.py, sent_emails, stat_catalog, static, user)
and if i do this: docker compose exec web ls -l /app/crm_market/collected_static:
(admin,
debug_toolbar,
grappelli)

It seems that it exists just does not have access to it, or maybe path is wrong.. thats my guess so far.

From your comment, I can't see that it exists. The command I suggested is a single command even though it's split over 2 lines. It looks like you only ran the part up until -l?

sorry, you right:
(venv) root@fuvscqxzga://root/CRM-WB# docker compose exec web ls -l /app/crm_market/collected_static/grappelli/js/grappelli.min.js
-rwxr-xr-x 1 www-data www-data 27906 Jun 25 09:15 /app/crm_market/collected_static/grappelli/js/grappelli.min.js

I don't see Nginx in compose file. How do you connect it to virtual volume with static files?

I assumed that web would connect to static. Ill try that now!

I installed it manually and set up at default location with sudo apt install nginx -y

/app/crm_market/collected_static exists in container only, not on host.

Just to be clear, is the error message coming from the web container or from Nginx?

from nginx and server worked fine the problem lies with static for admin. I made quite a bit of changes at this point it does not launch at all i will try to connect with nginx.conf and create a NGINX container.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75365356/nginx-does-not-seeing-static-files-when-launching-with-docker-compose-gunicorn

In short I solved the problem by adding nginx however i restructured a whole lot of my project.
