# Django Nginx Unable to serve Static Files

Tags: python-3.x, django, ubuntu, nginx, gunicorn

Nginx won't serve my Django static files while gunicorn serves as expected. I have my settings as:

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATICFILES_DIRS = [BASE_DIR / 'static']
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'staticfiles')
```

while my nginx.conf has:

```
events {}
http {
 server {
   listen 80;
   server_name 127.0.0.1 cloud101.dev www.cloud101.dev;

   # Correctly point to your static files directory
   # root /usr/src/app/staticfiles;

   location /static {
     root /usr/src/app/staticfiles;
   }

   location / {
     proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8000;
     proxy_set_header Host $host;
     proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
     proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
   }
```

the Dockerfile has:

```
# pull the official base image
FROM python:3.12.2-bullseye
...
# Install Nginx and dependencies
RUN apt-get install -y nginx
# copy project
COPY . /usr/src/app
COPY website/nginx.conf /etc/nginx/nginx.conf

EXPOSE 8000

RUN python manage.py collectstatic -v 2 --noinput

CMD ["gunicorn", "--bind", "0.0.0.0:8000", "website.wsgi:application"]
```

gunicorn serves alright but the static files are not served although the default server does. What am I missing?

Comment: Just realized that you have both django and nginx in one docker image. This is a bad practice, consider running each component in a separate container. Please have a look at this thread, see how nginx, django and other components are _composed_ together https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66774079/how-to-make-static-files-works-using-django-docker-nginx-and-postgresql-since-it/66777142#66777142

Answer (score 0):

Replace `root` with `alias`.

```
location /static {
     alias /usr/src/app/staticfiles;
   }
```

`root` means that defined *location* lies under given *root* folder. In your case it means `/usr/src/app/staticfiles/static` which is wrong. Your files are not in `staticfiles/static`, you just need to map url `/static` to folder `/usr/src/app/staticfiles` - this can be done with `alias` directive.

[root directive docs](https://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#root)

Comment: So far substituting root with alias as suggested doesnt give expected results

Comment: There can be more than one issue. After fixing location declaration please show current error message and how you connect nginx container with django container, how you "deliver" collected static files to nginx.

Comment: After installing Nginx, I install the configuration that points to statics in the collectstatic staticfiles directory.             RUN apt-get install -y nginx

COPY website/nginx.conf /etc/nginx/nginx.conf             The nginx.conf:  events {}
http {
 server {
   listen 80;
   server_name 127.0.0.1 cloud101.dev www.cloud101.dev;

   location /static {
     alias /usr/src/app/staticfiles;
   }

Comment: `RUN python manage.py collectstatic -v 2 --noinput` after running this your static files are still inside django docker container. You need to map virtual volume to the `staticfiles` folder and share it with nginx. If your django is not running in docker container then elaborate how you deliver static files to `/usr/src/app/staticfiles`.

Comment: Its running in a container but mapping to the staticfiles folder seems the issue which am yet to figure out

Comment: When I run the docker container interractively with debug set to True, I get the error: ''' Not Found: /static/blog/style.css '''

Comment: Listing files in the /usr/src/app/staticfiles I get:                RUN ls staticfiles       >>>>
admin,
blog,
fontawesome_free

Comment: Whereas using `root` was a mistake for sure there are clearly more issues in described config. Please take a look at this thread and at docker-compose example https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66774079/how-to-make-static-files-works-using-django-docker-nginx-and-postgresql-since-it/66777142#66777142

Comment: From an error after tweaking a template: <link rel="stylesheet" type='text/css' href="{% 'blog/css/nav.css' %}">     I can tell its mapping to the generated staticfiles since error shows it - Error during template rendering

In template /usr/src/app/blog/templates/blog/nav.html, error at line 24