Can't serve static files Django + Gunicorn + Nginx + Docker
I have the following structure on my project:

-> api_solar_django 
--> manage.py
--> api_app (where are the view.py model.py, etc)
--> api_solar (where are settings.py, etc)

In my docker-compose file I have the following:
services:
  django:
    build:
      context: ./api_solar_django
    container_name: django-app
    restart: unless-stopped
    ports:
      - "8090:8090"
    volumes:
      - ./api_solar_django:/app
      - static_volume:/app/static
    environment:
      - DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE=api_solar.settings
      - ENC_KEY=key
    depends_on:
      - db
    networks:
      - app-network

  
  nginx:
    image: nginx:alpine
    container_name: nginx
    restart: unless-stopped
    ports:
      - "80:80"
    volumes:
      - ./nginx.conf:/etc/nginx/nginx.conf:ro
      - static_volume:/static
    depends_on:
      - django
      - frontend
    networks:
      - app-network

networks:
  app-network:
    driver: bridge

volumes:
  postgres_data:
  static_volume:

The static files, inside each container is located as:

Django container: /app folder, same as manage.py
Nginx container: root folder

My nginx.conf file is configured as:
user nginx;
worker_processes auto;

error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log warn;
pid /var/run/nginx.pid;

events {
    worker_connections 1024;
}

http {
    include /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    default_type application/octet-stream;

    sendfile on;
    keepalive_timeout 65;

    # Incluindo o servidor configurado
    server {
        listen 80;

        # Serve arquivos estáticos do Django
        location /static/ {
            alias /static/;
        }

        # Proxy para o backend (Django)
        location /api/ {
            proxy_pass http://django-app:8090/;
            proxy_set_header Host $host;
            proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
        }

        # Proxy para o frontend (Vue.js)
        location / {
            proxy_pass http://vue-app:5173;
            proxy_set_header Host $host;
            proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
        }
    }
}

I am trying to access the admin panel via http://localhost:8090/admin/, although it works, it can't access the static files.

This might help you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66774079/how-to-make-static-files-works-using-django-docker-nginx-and-postgresql-since-it

Take a look at dockerfile and entrypoint.sh in mentioned question. If you're not collecting static files after django container startup then you're hiding/overriding real folder with files with the virtual volume. That's why it contains nothing.
