# Docker: Unable to start docker images/ unable to add path /etc/<folder_name>

Tags: docker

I'm fairly new to docker and development so I was hoping I could get some help here. I've seen this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45122459/docker-mounts-denied-the-paths-are-not-shared-from-os-x-and-are-not-known) but I don't quite understand the highlighted section and can't see how it applies to me. Basically, I get an error message:

```
ERROR: for webserver  Cannot start service webserver: b'Mounts denied: \r\nThe 
paths /etc/airflow and /etc/airflow\r\nare not shared from OS X and are not 
known to Docker.\r\nYou can configure shared paths from Docker -> 
Preferences... -> File Sharing.\r\nSee https://docs.docker.com/docker-for- 
mac/osxfs/#namespaces for more info.\r\n.'
```

This is my current [file sharing setup](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z0Wkd.png) in Docker. I tried adding /etc/airflow in the Docker for Mac file sharing preferences but I was unable to apply changes and restart because /etc is under /private. I've tried replacing /private with /etc/airflow but the problem persists. Any idea what I can do?

Comment: If you are new to docker, I would advice using Kitematic (for MAC). Its good tool which lets you map disks to your containers, change port numbers on the fly etc. Worth  trying !

Comment: @Abhi thanks for the suggestion, I'll give it a go. my problem is that I'm unable to set up a custom docker container that my company is using, and I'm not sure how hard that might be in kitematic