# Relative path binding in docker for volumes in macOS does fail

Tags: macos, docker, path, docker-compose, volumes

I am using docker-compose and I would like to create a relative two-path binding.

```
Folder structure and path at the host machine:
/Users/username/Documents/Repos/docker-gulp-template/bla
docker-gulp-template
  Dockerfile
  docker-compose.yml
  Bla (Folder)
```

```
Path structure inside the container:

/usr/src/html/bla
```

```
version: '3'
services:
  bla:
    command: /bin/bash    
    stdin_open: true
    #tty: true
    container_name: docker-gulp-template
    #restart: always
    build: .
    ports:
      - '80:3000'
    volumes:
      - "/bla:/usr/src/html/bla"
```

This one does result in an error.

```
ERROR: for docker-gulp-template  Cannot start service bla: b'Mounts denied: \r\nThe path /bla\r\nis not shared from OS X and is not known to Docker.\r\nYou can configure shared paths from Docker -> Preferences... -> File Sharing.\r\nSee https://docs.docker.com/docker-for-mac/osxfs/#namespaces for more info.\r\n.'
```

```
    volumes:
      - ".:/usr/src/html/bla"
```

This one does work.

I did found this thread:
[Docker: Mounts denied. The paths ... are not shared from OS X and are not known to Docker](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45122459/docker-mounts-denied-the-paths-are-not-shared-from-os-x-and-are-not-known)

but it didn't help me at all.
I did try to add my repository-folder to the file sharing tab of the docker settings but it doesn't allow me to add the folder because it is already inside the group of /Users.

Is the path relative from the docker-compose/docker file?

Anybody got an idea what the problem is? I am really confused.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Do you use the latest Docker for Mac?

Comment: Yes I do. The mistake was a missing dot in front of the path.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use relative paths, in your case it would be

```
volumes:
  - "./Bla:/usr/src/html/bla"
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. This answer was very helpfull. Didn't know that I have to use . before.

Comment: @Burg I did not see in docs you should. looks like it's needed to distinguish from volumes.

Comment: this works with the quotes, i was missing quotes and it does not work without them, but absolute paths work without comments it seems. im using version `3.8`

Answer (score 1):

I think I did found the solution to my own problem.

To do a two-way-binding it looks like you have to use:

```
$PWD
```

Inside the hostpath.

In my case:

```
  volumes:
      - "$PWD/bla:/usr/src/html/bla"
```

After that it does work. Is this a good solution or does it create any problems which I don't know?

Comment: that's ok. $PWD expands to **full** path, not relative. looks to me now relative paths cannot be used...

Comment: @AlexeiMartianov relative to what directory? Having absolute path to the current directory (that `$pwd` returns) you can then specify path relative to it.