# Docker error: Error response from daemon: Mounts denied: on OS X

Tags: macos, docker, settings, docker-machine

I've currently a problem and can't find a solution. I've created an apps folder in my document directory of my user and set it as apps path in the config. When I try to run the docker I get following error:

> Error response from daemon: Mounts denied: The path
>   /users/username/documents/development/docker-apps is not shared from
>   OS X and is not known to Docker. You can configure shared paths from
>   Docker -> Preferences... -> File Sharing.

I've added the `/Users` in the preferences globally but the issue is still there:

[image]

When I try to add the path I get an error massage that it's not possible because I've added the /Users globally.

My research ended with no helpful answers so I would really appreciate if you can help me with this problem.

Comment: How are you running the docker run command ?

Comment: sudo python run.py. This is a script from a college which runs all of the stuff.

Comment: Maybe we will need to check what is inside that python file.  Did you try docker hello world and some other images before that? A simple image sharing a volume for example..

Comment: So I've checked the file. First this gets runned: call(["docker-compose", "build"]) after this, the script runs this: call(["sudo", "docker-compose", "run", "--service-ports", "oap"])

Comment: Please try a simple docker run command before running that python. 
Example: docker run -ti -v $PWD:/app alpine

I thought that your problem is not in docker and share preferences.

Comment: And it's my first image. I've don't tried anything before

Comment: This is shown in the console when I run your command: dquote>

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/187491/discussion-between-flavio-silveira-and-mr-jo).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've found the problem. It seems that OS X with Docker has a problem with the path. On Linux all works fine but in OS X not. So when you write this here in the terminal, it will work but not in the Docker:

```
/users/username/documents/development/docker-apps
```

So when you add another / at the end like this:

```
/users/username/documents/development/docker-apps/
```

it will work.

Comment: Adding a  /  at the end of the Path did not work for me. However, when I run docker run script as sudo, it worked.

Comment: @RahulSaini This can happen if you installed it as sudo user.

Answer (score 3):

For MacOS Docker 3.0 or higher answer provided by
François Alexandre

[Docker: Mounts denied. The paths ... are not shared from OS X and are not known to Docker](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45122459/docker-mounts-denied-the-paths-are-not-shared-from-os-x-and-are-not-known/45123074)

> "With the new version 3.0.0 of Docker for mac, you need to disable use
> gRPC FUSE for file sharing in Preferences>Experimental Features."

Answer (score 1):

For me it was running docker run shell script as sudo that resolved the issue.

IND00237:dispatcher-sdk-2.0.22 rahul.saini$ **./bin/docker_run.sh ./out host.docker.internal:4503 8080**

docker: Error response from daemon: Mounts denied:
The paths /users/rahul.saini/aem-cloud-sdk/aem-sdk-2020.6.3766.20200619T110731Z-200604/dispatcher-sdk-2.0.22/out/vhosts_conf and /users/rahul.saini/aem-cloud-sdk/aem-sdk-2020.6.3766.20200619T110731Z-200604/dispatcher-sdk-2.0.22/out/custom_vars and /users/rahul.saini/aem-cloud-sdk/aem-sdk-2020.6.3766.20200619T110731Z-200604/dispatcher-sdk-2.0.22/out/global_vars and /users/rahul.saini/aem-cloud-sdk/aem-sdk-2020.6.3766.20200619T110731Z-200604/dispatcher-sdk-2.0.22/out/rules_any and /users/rahul.saini/aem-cloud-sdk/aem-sdk-2020.6.3766.20200619T110731Z-200604/dispatcher-sdk-2.0.22/out/filters_any and /users/rahul.saini/aem-cloud-sdk/aem-sdk-2020.6.3766.20200619T110731Z-200604/dispatcher-sdk-2.0.22/out/rewrite_rules and /users/rahul.saini/aem-cloud-sdk/aem-sdk-2020.6.3766.20200619T110731Z-200604/dispatcher-sdk-2.0.22/out/farms_any and /users/rahul.saini/aem-cloud-sdk/aem-sdk-2020.6.3766.20200619T110731Z-200604/dispatcher-sdk-2.0.22/out/clientheaders_any and /users/rahul.saini/aem-cloud-sdk/aem-sdk-2020.6.3766.20200619T110731Z-200604/dispatcher-sdk-2.0.22/out/virtualhosts_any
are not shared from OS X and are not known to Docker.
You can configure shared paths from Docker -> Preferences... -> File Sharing.
See https://docs.docker.com/docker-for-mac/osxfs/#namespaces for more info.
.
ERRO[0000] error waiting for container: context canceled

IND00237:dispatcher-sdk-2.0.22 rahul.saini$ **sudo su**
Password:
sh-3.2# cd /Users/rahul.saini/aem-cloud-sdk/aem-sdk-2020.6.3766.20200619T110731Z-200604/dispatcher-sdk-2.0.22/

sh-3.2# **./bin/docker_run.sh ./out host.docker.internal:4503 8080**
Running script /docker_entrypoint.d/10-check-environment.sh
Running script /docker_entrypoint.d/20-create-docroots.sh
Running script /docker_entrypoint.d/30-wait-for-backend.sh
Waiting until host.docker.internal is available
host.docker.internal resolves to 192.168.65.2
Running script /docker_entrypoint.d/40-generate-allowed-clients.sh
Running script /docker_entrypoint.d/50-check-expiration.sh
Running script /docker_entrypoint.d/60-check-loglevel.sh
Running script /docker_entrypoint.d/70-check-forwarded-host-secret.sh
Starting httpd server
[Wed Jul 01 08:05:16.270293 2020] [:notice] [pid 1:tid 140296106285960] ModSecurity for Apache/2.9.2 (http://www.modsecurity.org/) configured.
[Wed Jul 01 08:05:16.270332 2020] [:notice] [pid 1:tid 140296106285960] ModSecurity: APR compiled version="1.6.3"; loaded version="1.6.3"
[Wed Jul 01 08:05:16.270337 2020] [:notice] [pid 1:tid 140296106285960] ModSecurity: PCRE compiled version="8.42 "; loaded version="8.42 2018-03-20"
[Wed Jul 01 08:05:16.270339 2020] [:notice] [pid 1:tid 140296106285960] ModSecurity: LIBXML compiled version="2.9.8"
[Wed Jul 01 08:05:16.270341 2020] [:notice] [pid 1:tid 140296106285960] ModSecurity: Status engine is currently disabled, enable it by set SecStatusEngine to On.
[Wed Jul 01 08:05:16.341071 2020] [mpm_worker:notice] [pid 1:tid 140296106285960] AH00292: Apache/2.4.43 (Unix) Communique/4.3.4-20200424 mod_qos/11.63 configured -- resuming normal operations
[Wed Jul 01 08:05:16.341107 2020] [core:notice] [pid 1:tid 140296106285960] AH00094: Command line: 'httpd -d /etc/httpd -f /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf -D FOREGROUND -D ENVIRONMENT_DEV'