# How to mount volume to docker on OSX?

Tags: macos, docker, docker-volume, docker-desktop

I have a problem mounting a host machine volume to a docker image.  I've added a folder to docker File sharing settings, but it doesn't get any effect. What do I have to do to solve the problem?

For example, I try to mount a volume which was added to File sharing settings in Docker Desktop, but I get permission denied error

```sh
~$ docker run --rm -it -v /Users/:/vm-root alpine ls -l /vm-root
docker: Error response from daemon: Mounts denied: EOF.
ERRO[0000] error waiting for container: context canceledenter code here
```

Docker Desktop Screenshot:

[image: Volume already added to file sharing settings in docker desktop]

Comment: Also, you have overlapping directories. I suggest only exporting `/Users/username` directories and avoid `/Users`

Comment: 1. the result doesn't depend by the last backslash 
2. overlapping dir was the attempt solving the problem

Answer (score 1):

You have overlapping directories. I suggest only exporting `/Users/username` directories and avoid `/Users`

Answer (score 1):

Solution prvided by François Alexandre
[Docker: Mounts denied. The paths ... are not shared from OS X and are not known to Docker](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45122459/docker-mounts-denied-the-paths-are-not-shared-from-os-x-and-are-not-known/45123074)

> With the new version 3.0.0 of Docker for mac, you need to disable use
> gRPC FUSE for file sharing in Preferences>Experimental Features.