# How to stop my mount from being denied in docker?

Tags: docker, docker-for-mac

I ran the following command:
`sudo docker run -d -p 127.0.0.1:9200:9200 -v /PATH/TO/geoname_index/data/:/usr/share/elasticsearch/data elasticsearch:5.1.2`                        
Which yielded the following response:

```
(base) myname@myname-MacBook-Pro es-geonames % sudo docker run -d -p 127.0.0.1:9200:9200 -v /PATH/TO/geoname_index/data/:/usr/share/elasticsearch/data elasticsearch:5.1.2                        

WARNING: The requested image's platform (linux/amd64) does not match the detected host platform (linux/arm64/v8) and no specific platform was requested
4a706e62e91acfbae714cc6a33e270aedfaf84069c4bb5668187958d78cb8472
docker: Error response from daemon: Mounts denied: 
The path /PATH/TO/geoname_index/data is not shared from the host and is not known to Docker.
You can configure shared paths from Docker -> Preferences... -> Resources -> File Sharing.
See https://docs.docker.com/desktop/mac for more info.
```

I have tried adding the path to `geoname_index` to Docker's File Sharing settings, but when I hit `Apply & Restart`, the path disappears from the settings window.

I've read the following articles:
https://medium.com/@lynzt/learning-docker-error-mounts-denied-mac-73307b49f545

[Mounts denied. The paths ... are not shared from OS X and are not known to Docker](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45122459/mounts-denied-the-paths-are-not-shared-from-os-x-and-are-not-known-to-docke)

**Please let me know if there's any information I can provide to help answer this question**

Comment: Can you try this solution, of disabling gRPC FUSE for Mac? https://stackoverflow.com/a/65258434/530160

Comment: @NickODell This helped! I had to delete the /User shared folder to add my folder's path, since they're overlapping!