How can I get my .NET 8 web app to properly decrypt data protected when it was running on .NET 6?
I have an ASP.NET Core web application that uses data protection to encrypt/decrypt values stored in a database. The app was original written in .NET 3.1, later migrated to .NET 6, and now to .NET 8. The problem I am having is that after upgrading to .NET 8, the app encounters an error trying to decrypt the previously stored values. Reverting to .NET 6 enables the decryption to work correctly again.
Here is the relevant part of Startup.cs:
services.AddDataProtection()
    .PersistKeysToFileSystem(new DirectoryInfo(keysPath));

Here is what I see in the logs:
2024-04-30 11:54:07.8247 DEBUG Microsoft.AspNetCore.DataProtection.KeyManagement.XmlKeyManager Found key {7e33d995-90ef-4e91-95bc-68f44e50c4dc}.
2024-04-30 11:54:07.8247 DEBUG Microsoft.AspNetCore.DataProtection.KeyManagement.XmlKeyManager Found key {827bc86d-f9c8-4edc-b2b8-0f38a19775ca}.
2024-04-30 11:54:07.8247 DEBUG Microsoft.AspNetCore.DataProtection.KeyManagement.XmlKeyManager Found key {85752c41-0db1-4855-bd3d-1be5fb7948db}.
2024-04-30 11:54:07.8247 DEBUG Microsoft.AspNetCore.DataProtection.KeyManagement.XmlKeyManager Found key {b7190f71-d798-4564-b644-414650ca839d}.
2024-04-30 11:54:07.8247 DEBUG Microsoft.AspNetCore.DataProtection.KeyManagement.XmlKeyManager Found key {c10175df-a4c2-4e6a-abf3-7b6ba52fd577}.
2024-04-30 11:54:07.8247 DEBUG Microsoft.AspNetCore.DataProtection.KeyManagement.XmlKeyManager Found key {c5640c90-8bd7-4032-800a-1615f18d0c1e}.
2024-04-30 11:54:07.8247 DEBUG Microsoft.AspNetCore.DataProtection.KeyManagement.XmlKeyManager Found key {e4b11e1a-74ac-4ef9-82c9-0299a0885ac5}.
2024-04-30 11:54:07.8247 DEBUG Microsoft.AspNetCore.DataProtection.KeyManagement.DefaultKeyResolver Considering key {e4b11e1a-74ac-4ef9-82c9-0299a0885ac5} with expiration date 2024-06-03 20:36:56Z as default key.
...
2024-04-30 11:54:07.8247 DEBUG Microsoft.AspNetCore.DataProtection.KeyManagement.KeyRingProvider Using key {e4b11e1a-74ac-4ef9-82c9-0299a0885ac5} as the default key.
...
2024-04-30 11:54:07.8561 ERROR Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query An exception occurred while iterating over the results of a query for context type 'MyApp.AppDbContext'.
System.Security.Cryptography.CryptographicException: The key {ca4f6f42-0963-42b4-901d-306088846261} was not found in the key ring. For more information go to https://aka.ms/aspnet/dataprotectionwarning

As the logs state, the first seven keys do exist in the key storage directory, and the last one is still valid. But then it ignores those and comes up with an entirely new one that does not exist, causing the decryption to fail.
How can I get the .NET 8 version of the app to use the existing valid key to decrypt the data rather than creating a new key that will fail?

https://stackoverflow.com/a/76957135/2385435 this guy describes something similar being solved by clearing cookies (?!)

As the error message said: "The key {ca4f6f42-0963-42b4-901d-306088846261} was not found in the key ring." Please check your key configuration, ensure the key exist.

Check this article:  If you change the key persistence location, the system no longer automatically encrypts keys at rest, since it doesn't know whether DPAPI is an appropriate encryption mechanism. So you can try to store the keys to DbContext or Azure KeyVault. And you can configure the system to protect keys at rest by calling any of the ProtectKeysWith* configuration APIs, or change the algorithms.

@ZhiLv Thank you for your comments. The key is not found in the key ring, I acknowledged that in my post. My question is more "Why is it not using a valid key in the key ring?" and "How do I force it to use a valid existing key?"  Also, the keys are not encrypted at rest, and the location of the key storage has not changed between the two versions of the app. The only change is targeting .NET 8 instead of .NET 6.

are you publishing to the same directory?  If not, that may be the issue as it will try to isolate different apps.  It'll use the path as sort of app id.

@browsermator It's published in an Azure pipeline as a zip file. Deploying the update consists of unzipping into the same directory where the .NET 6 version is deployed.

Since the log suggests this happens while iterating DB results, this might be DB encryption?  If so, you might try checking for revoked keys?  See here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/data-protection/consumer-apis/dangerous-unprotect?view=aspnetcore-8.0

also make sure the zip file does not contain the persisted key file.  That'll get out of sync pretty quick.

@browsermator Thank you for the suggestions. I don't believe it's DB encryption because the app reads other unprotected data just fine. Also, when running the .NET 6 version against the same database, with the same keys, the values are decrypted correctly. The keys are persisted in another directory, outside of the application directory. As a side note, which may or may not be relevant, the existing keys in the key ring were created under the .NET 6 version.

Just a shot in the dark, but you might check here : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/data-protection/configuration/overview?view=aspnetcore-8.0#setapplicationname  There is a warning about .NET 6 and it's path.  It adds an ending slash which would effect the application discriminator.  It's not real clear if .NET 8 does the same, but it shows a workaround to remove the ending slash.
